# ReactJS warning [Violation] 'input' handler took <N>ms. And then the navigator is freeze

Tags: reactjs

Do you have this problem?
I really really stocked.
This is my code but I dont know how to solve.
When the user is writing his his email with many characters the screen is freezing, the console send a yellow warning message: " 'input' handler took ms " I try to set a debouncetime and use lodash/debounce but without success

```
export const useForm = (data, setData, validForm) => {

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({email: 'write email'})

    const handleChange = (event) => {

        if (!!!event?.target?.name && !!!event?.target?.value) return console.log({event})

        setData({
            ...data,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    const handleBlur = (event) => {
        handleChange(event);
        setErrors(validForm(data))
    }

    const clearErrors = (event) => {
        setErrors({});
    }

    return {errors, handleChange, handleBlur, clearErrors}

}


function App() {

    const [dataSelectError, setDataSelectError] = useState({
        email: {email: false}
    })

    const [dataformCustomer, setDataFormCustomer] = useState({email: ''})

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log({dataformCustomer});
        handleBlur(dataformCustomer)

    }, [dataformCustomer])

    const validCustomer = (data) => {
        let errors = {};
        let regexEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)@\w+([\.-]?\w+)(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

        if (data.email.trim().length === 0) {
            errors.email = 'write email'
        } else if (!regexEmail.test(data.email.trim())) {
            errors.email = 'invalid'
        }

        return errors

    }

    const {
        errors,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur
    } = useForm(dataformCustomer, setDataFormCustomer, validCustomer)

    useEffect(() => {

        let vehicleErrors = {}

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataSelectError)) {
            if (value.error) {
                vehicleErrors = key;
            }
        }

    }, [errors, dataSelectError]);

    return (
        <form>
            <input
                autoComplete="off"
                aria-autocomplete="off"
                className="input-form"
                placeholder="CORREO ELECTRONICO"
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={dataformCustomer.email}
                onChange={handleChange}/>
            {errors?.email && <InfoError msg={errors?.email} type={"error"}/>}
   </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Is regex, is very expensive, y only replace for this:

let regexEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/